# Will a new Instance without a variable reference be garbage collected in Java?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, garbage-collection

Regarding the following Java classes:

```
public class GuiController {
    private GuiView view;

    public GuiController(GuiView view){
        this.view =  view;
    }

    //responds to user inputs to GuiView
}

public class GuiView {
    //interacts with user
}

//lives in the Servlet context
public class SomeLongLifeClass {
    private GuiView view;

    public SomeLongLifeClass(){
        this.view = new GuiView();
        new GuiController(view);
    }
}
```

Will GuiController eventually be garbage collected since it has no external references? It shouldn't be since it actively interacts with `GuiView` which is referenced, I just can't work out why.

In a secondary question how else should one implement a View/Controller pattern if not like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is, yes, your GuiController instance is eligible for GC. In a more realistic code, you'll probably register the controller as a listener (directly or indirectly) to GuiView components, and the controller will thus be referenced from the view, which itself is referenced by the GUI thread.

Comment: Great that explains it, however I'd like to clarify further, if the class GuiController now contains a sub class which implements some Listener and only that sub-class is registered as a listener to GuiViewer, is the Parent class (GuiController) referenced automatically by its sub-class?